# Copy objects into arraylist instead of pointing

Tags: java, pointers, arraylist, dijkstra

I am trying to create an arraylist of the nodes used to come from one place(node) to another. The nick is the name of the place and a Node's pi is the previous node in the path.

```
ArrayList<Node> bestWay = new ArrayList<Node>();
while(chosen.nick != from){
    bestWay.add(chosen);
    chosen = chosen.pi;
}
```

The problem is that all the elements in *bestWay* becomes the same. When I print *bestWay* I just get **PLACE1, PLACE1, PLACE1, PLACE1**, and not **PLACE1, PLACE2, PLACE3, PLACE4**.

Is it possible to copy the elements into the array, and not add pointers to the chosen-element which changes on the line after. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: If the `nick` variable name is a String, its best practice to actually use the `equals()` method ( sorry, I had to point that out). To store copies, either use the `clone()` method (and possibly override it on Node for your own use) or you can have a copy constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example trying to mimic what you explained. It works for me hence, the error should be somewhere else i guess:

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Node> bestWay = new ArrayList<Node>();
        Node chosen = new Node("Place1");
        String from = chosen
                .add("Place2")
                .add("Place3")
                .add("Place4")
                .add("Place5")
                .nick;
        while (chosen.nick != from) {
            bestWay.add(chosen);
            chosen = chosen.pi;
        }
        System.out.println(bestWay);
    }
}

class Node {

    final String nick;
    Node pi;

    Node(String nick) { this.nick = nick; }

    public Node add(String nick) {
        pi = new Node(nick);
        return pi;
    }

    @Override public String toString() {
        return nick;
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
[Place1, Place2, Place3, Place4]
```

Comment: Although your code didn't help me much, the fact that it worked for you helped me looking elsewhere for the problem. The problem was that I was still printing out chosen.nick, and not the elements in the new array. How foolish. Thanks a lot, though :)

Answer (score 0):

so I'd put this in a comment, but my rep isn't high enough. I had a similiar problem in C# a while back and I think the problem was solved by instantiating a new list component variable inside the loop. Not promising it will work but it's worth a try. Something like

```
ArrayList<Node> bestWay = new ArrayList<Node>();
  while(chosen.nick != from){
  Node dummy = new Node();
  dummy = chosen;

  bestWay.add(dummy);
  chosen = chosen.pi;      
}
```

Comment: I actually tried this just before I posted this question, and it did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Inside while, the first line: `bestWay.add(chosen);` adds a record to bestWay.

After this you have done: `chosen = chosen.pi;` this changes the reference of chosen object to the reference of chosen.pi, so this also changes the value you added to the `arraylist bestway`. That is the reason you are getting same value in arraylist.

If your Node class can be cloned then you can do the following:

```
ArrayList<Node> bestWay = new ArrayList<Node>();
while(chosen.nick != from){
    bestWay.add(chosen);
    chosen = chosen.pi.clone();
}
```

or this:

```
ArrayList<Node> bestWay = new ArrayList<Node>();
while(chosen.nick != from){
    bestWay.add(chosen.clone());
    chosen = chosen.pi;
}
```

if the Node class is not clonable yet, then you can write your custom code for clone by overridding clone method in the Node class.

hope this helps